# How to reload the recycler view

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android application to save the passwords.
On the main screen i am using recycler view to show all the passwords.
I have 2 two buttons one to add new password and second to update the password, when the user clicks on add new password, new activity (add new password activity) will be open. how should i reload the recycler view on the main screen after returning from the add new password activity?

i tried to recall the initial recyclerview function but it didn't worked.

```
addData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                action to be performed after it was clicked;
                Intent i = new Intent(MainScreen.this, AddNewPassword.class);
                i.putExtra("id", (String) null);
                i.putExtra("Platform", "");
                i.putExtra("User", "");
                i.putExtra("password", "");
                i.putExtra("boolean", false);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });
```

how should i refresh the current screen after returning fromm the AddNewPassword activity ?

Comment: Please add a minimal, compact, code snippet of what you are trying to do.

Comment: initialize your recyclerview onStart but first clear all the data and the set the new data to recyclerview adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While comming back to first you have to override onResume method and in that method you have to bind that recyclerAdapter and last call.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 1):

Call notifyDataSetChanged after making changes:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```